# Libreoffice macro basic: skip to next paragraph test for upper case

Tags: macros, libreoffice, basic

I'm trying to write a macro, and I need to skip to the next paragraph, where I will test the first letter for capitalization. I've spent hours and have only found inaccurate or hard to follow documentation for something that I think should be simple. Any direction would be appreciated. So far I have:

```
SUB FIND_PARAGRAPHS

Dim vDescriptor
dim Doc as object
dim Replace as object 
dim oCursor 
dim Proceed as Boolean
dim CapTest as String

vDescriptor = ThisComponent.createSearchDescriptor()
doc = ThisComponent
dispatcher = createUnoService("com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper")

' test para begin; if capital test previous end 

oCursor = Doc.Text.createTextCursor()
Do 
    oCursor.gotoNextParagraph(false) 'NW
    CapTest = oCursor.goRight(1, true) 'NW
    if CapTest = ucase(CapTest) Then goto TestPreviousEnd
Loop While CapTest

TestPreviousEnd:

END SUB
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems:

- [goRight()](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/text/XTextCursor.html#goRight) returns a boolean to indicate success, not the selected string.
- `CapsTest` is a string, not a boolean, so it cannot be used as the loop condition.
- How did you know the code wasn't working?  Perhaps you intended to use the [view cursor](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Writer/API/View_cursor), which would cause the visible cursor to move.  (However a text cursor is probably better).
- The code always ignores the first paragraph, which may be intentional but seems strange.
- There are a lot of unused variables, and the capitalization is inconsistent.

Here is working code:

```vb
' Find the first paragraph in the document that begins with a capital letter.
Sub Find_Capitalized_Paragraph
    Dim oDoc As Object
    Dim oCursor As Object
    Dim Proceed As Boolean
    Dim CapTest As String

    oDoc = ThisComponent
    oCursor = oDoc.Text.createTextCursor()
    oCursor.gotoStart(False)
    Do 
        oCursor.goRight(1, True)
        CapTest = oCursor.getString()
        If CapTest <> "" And CapTest = UCase(CapTest) Then Goto TestPreviousEnd
        oCursor.gotoNextParagraph(False)
    Loop While CapTest <> ""
    MsgBox("No results.")
    Exit Sub

    TestPreviousEnd:
    MsgBox("Found result: """ & CapTest & """")
End Sub
```

So if the document contains:

```
a
b
C
d
```

Then the macro prints `Found result: "C"`.

Be sure to check out [Andrew Pitonyak's macro document](http://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php).  It contains many excellent examples.

Comment: Thanks so much for that detailed analysis. I will examine this later and get back.

Comment: I've checked this out and it's working fine, and I've learned quite a bit from it. Hitting the first paragraph isn't important, since I'm trying to pick paragraphs out from unnecessary linefeeds, and the first para is obviously a para. (Strange, I can't start a new para here without tripping the "Save edits" command.) IAC, I can use this and build on it for what I'm trying to do. I have found the documentation very difficult to follow, including the resource you linked to, which I already had. Thanks again and be well.